# Getting the currency code by a country in Flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization, locale

I have a Flutter application, running on both iOS and Android.

I need to add a piece of code to get the **currency code** by a **country** (e.g. the user chooses on a map).

Now, I'm aware of the **intl** package and the **NumberFormat** thing;

```
  // Use the intl package to get the currency code for the specified locale
  NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: locale.toString());
```

My point that it works only for *well defined* locales, e.g. **en_US** (English in the USA) or **fr_FR** (French in France), where the locale's language is one of the supported languages for that country.

It will give apparently wrong results (EUR) for *mixed* locales, e.g. **fr_US** (French language in the USA).

I.e., apparently, in the case of a "invalid" combination of language and country, the **intl** package implements fetching the locale based on the language rather on the country.

An empty language code as well as a dummy one while constructing a Locale just crashes the code.

Hence, I need a way to get the (or one of the supported) language's code for that country in order to prepare a correct locale.